# Multiple Search Results Tabs From Mulltiple "Find In Files" Actions

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

In Delphi 7 when i ran multiple Find In Files searches each search result would generate a separate tab. We've since upgraded to Delphi 2010 and now when i run multiple Find In Files searches each time one is fired off it replaces the tab instead of creating a new one with the results of the successive search. Is there a way to get the old functionality back, a setting somewhere?

Thank you,

Brian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Find in Files dialog, there is an option "Display results in separate tab".  Make sure that is checked, and the behavior should be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using a vertical grid for that. DevExpress' VerticalGrid can duplicate that functionality.